# Bash: any file in current directory

Tags: bash

Is there a shorthand in bash to select an arbitrary file? `*` enumerates all files in the current directory, but what if I only want one file and don't care which it is?

FWIW I'm testing several different ffmpeg commands in a directory with similarly named video files, so tab-complete is cumbersome.

Comment: Do you want, say, a random file so you get different results each time? Or is it okay to always just pick the first one? You could just grab `*` in a list and pick one out of there using `1` or `$RANDOM`.

Comment: @AndrewJanke either is fine: random or the same one. I'm ideally hoping for something only a few characters long so that it can be easily retyped when prototyping different commands. I suppose this could be solved by using `mv` to rename any file to a single character, but I'd rather use an approach without renaming, which is messy because it must be done manually. This is bad if filenames are meaningful (and the user is not careful to `mv` back properly).

Comment: Would something like `find . -type f -print -quit` work for your case?

Comment: Well, you can't inline this conveniently, but `file=$(f=(*); echo ${f[0]})` will grab a file and then you can just call it `$file` in your subsequent commands. Wrap it in a `pick_a_file()` function if you want reusability.

Comment: @livibetter That works! Can you think of any way to make it shorter, e.g., save the expression to some kind of executable variable so that it has to be typed out in full only once?

Comment: @Aprel `foobar='find . -type f -print -quit'`, Enter. `$foobar`, Enter.

Comment: @Aprel But wait, ain't you asking about scripting? If so, why do you need to type multiple times? If not, write a script, really.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the robust way of getting the first or a random file in a directory, handling the edge case of not having any files:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Let globs expand to 0 elements instead of themselves if no matches
shopt -s nullglob  

# Add all the files in the current dir to an array
files=(*)

# Check if the array has any elements
if [[ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]]
then
    first_file=${files[0]}
    random_file=${files[RANDOM%${#files[@]}]}

    echo "The first file is ${first_file}"
    echo "A random file is ${random_file}"
else
    echo "There are no files in the current directory."
fi
```

If you just want something short and hacky for interactive testing, you can create an array and reference it unindexed to get the first element with minimal typing:

```
$ testfile=( *.avi )
$ ffmpeg -i "$testfile" test.mp3
```

You can also bind <kbd>Tab</kbd> to zsh style completion:

```
$ bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

now, for the rest of this session, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> you'll get a complete filename instead of just a prefix (press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to cycle through matches). This will let you conveniently pick a file with a single keystroke.

Comment: Nice hack! Has the added bonus of wildcard matching if you want a specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I was using the `shuf`:

```
find -name '*whatever*' | shuf | head -n 1
```

The `shuf` is a tool, part of GNU coreutils, which prints the input lines in random order. In other words, it *shuf*fles the lines.